# what will be the value for revision_id field . Records are inserted with csv?

Tags: 8, nodes

I have created the field for the custom content type . I want to update field value for some node . So I am trying to upload with csv direct in the phpmyadmin .But I  want to know about the "REVISION ID" value . What will be the value for the particular field table

I have try to install **FEEDS** module but its also not working for drupal 8

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand what you're asking, but I can tell you this: doing updates directly in your database with phpmyadmin is likely to cause problems. Please consider using the Drupal API's. For instance, you could create your own module and [implement hook_update_N()](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/update-api/introduction-to-update-api-for-drupal-8) to load, change and save every node you need to update. This way you don't even need to know the revision_id value.

Comment: i have try with this hook and i dont know what will be the value of N . I have try with the 8001,8201,8501

Comment: The value of N does not really matter much, as long as it starts with 8 and is higher than the previous hook_update_N you implemented before. If it's a new module with an empty .install file, 8001 is the obvious choice. It *must* be in the .install file. Make sure to enable the module and run database updates, either from /update.php or using `drush updb`.